# TYPO3 typeNum with speaking url

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

The type is always specified as follows:

```
www.domain.com/?type=123456
```

However, I would like to pass this along with a speaking URL.

```
www.domain.com/123456
```

I assumed that was possible. But I couldn't find anything about routeEnhanced in the TYPO3 documentation.

My target is to use it to return a JSON.

My question, how do I get the "type" in a speaking URL?

Answer (score 2):

you would use the RouteEnhander of type PageType

in your case you would create a map of

```
        map:
            /: 0
            '123456': 123456
```

but i would argue that its better to map it to somthing meaningufll

```
        map:
            /: 0
            '/print.html': 123456
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#routing-pagetype-decorator

Comment: OK. Yes, it works. But unfortunately the arguments are not transmitted.

Comment: You mean other arguments beside type?

Comment: TYPO3 has protection against argument "stuffing" so additional arguments need to be signed by cHash or need to be mapped via RoutingConfiguration.